# Flutter null safety animation : The argument type 'Animation<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>'

Tags: flutter

Hello I try to make null safety migration. I have this working code in old version, but with null safety I have an error with animation:

```
The argument type 'Animation<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>'
```

---

Here est my code

```
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late  Animation<Offset> offset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
 _animation= CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.elasticOut);

   offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.6), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
    .animate(_animation);

offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.6))
    .animate(_animation);
  }
```

I tried         .animate(_animation.value);  to remove error but it does'nt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Animation<dynamic> _animation` use `Animation<double> _animation`

Check this link for reference
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/CurvedAnimation-class.html

```
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<Offset> offset;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.elasticOut);

    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.6), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
        .animate(_animation);

    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.6))
        .animate(_animation);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just forgot the <double>   late Animation _animation; =>  late Animation<double> _animation;

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix it

1. Add type notation to your `_animation` var like:

```
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late  Animation<Offset> offset;
  late Animation<double> _animation;//FIX HERE!

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
 _animation= CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.elasticOut);

   offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.6), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
    .animate(_animation);

offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.6))
    .animate(_animation);
  }//everything works
```

2. Just use `animation` as a local variable like this:

```
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<Offset> offset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
    final animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.elasticOut); //FIX HERE!

    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.6), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
        .animate(animation);

    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.6))
        .animate(animation);//everything works
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just forgot the <double> from late Animation _animation; => late Animation<double> _animation;

Comment: @Nitneuq I was the first one to give the correct answer and I have given two ways to fix it, and you approve the answer from another - not cool